# Qt 5.5.1 msvc2015 build error

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm trying to build Qt 5.5.1 from sources on Windows 10 with with msvc2015.

It was configured with:

```
configure.bat -release -opensource -c++11 -no-angle -opengl dynamic -shared -confirm-license -make libs -make tools -nomake examples -platform win32-msvc2015 -target xp -no-iconv -no-fontconfig -no-system-proxies -no-icu -qmake -no-rtti -strip -no-libproxy -no-dbus -no-qml-debug -mp
```

With this config and every time I try to change -opengl option I get an error without any meaningful message:

```
    cl -c -FIqt_gui_pch.h -Yuqt_gui_pch.h -Fp.pch\release\Qt5Gui_pch.pch -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Os -MD -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -MP -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_BUILD_GUI_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_USE_BUNDLED_LIBPNG -DPNG_ARM_NEON_OPT=0 -DQT_ENABLE_HARFBUZZ_NG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_DYNAMIC_CAST -DNDEBUG -I. -I..\..\include -I..\..\include\QtGui -I..\..\include\QtGui\5.5.1 -I..\..\include\QtGui\5.5.1\QtGui -Itmp -I..\3rdparty\libpng -I..\3rdparty\zlib -I..\3rdparty\harfbuzz-ng\include -I..\3rdparty\zlib -I..\..\include\QtCore\5.5.1 -I..\..\include\QtCore\5.5.1\QtCore -I..\..\include\QtCore -I.moc\release -I..\..\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fo.obj\release\ @C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\qpixmapcache.obj.5800.148640.jom
moc_qbrush.cpp
moc_qplatformbackingstore.cpp
moc_qopenglshaderprogram.cpp
moc_qpainter.cpp
moc_qpdfwriter.cpp
moc_qvalidator.cpp
qdesktopservices.cpp
moc_qopengltimerquery.cpp
qpixmapcache.cpp
moc_qopenglengineshadermanager_p.cpp
        link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 /VERSION:5.5 /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\..\lib\Qt5Gui.dll @C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\Qt5Gui.dll.5800.153390.jom
   Creating library ..\..\lib\Qt5Gui.lib and object ..\..\lib\Qt5Gui.exp
        copy /y ..\..\lib\Qt5Gui.dll ..\..\bin
        1 file(s) copied.
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1-msvc2015-shared-min\qtbase\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1-msvc2015-shared-min\Makefile [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I run Windows 10 under VirtualBox if it matters.

What could be the reason of the error and how to fix it?

Comment: The reason for the error should be above this output in the log.

Comment: Did you install ActivePerl and ActivePython before building?

Comment: Yes, ActivePerl, ActivePython and Ruby installed. Where can I find the output log? I build with `jom` if it matters.

Comment: ***Where can I find the output log?*** Sorry. I was talking about the build output that you posted. This would not normally be saved in a file but you could easily pipe the output to a file or increase the scrollback buffer on the window and capture more output than you display.